# how to determine the existence of a subgroup that passes given criteria?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

As a part of a homework assignment I'm required to write a function, that returns true if a "good" subgroup exists in the array it is given.
A "good subgroup" is a subgroup that the sum of a specific field(which is an integer) in each of the group members is bigger than a given target(specifically half of the original length of the array), and each member of the group is "getting along" with all of the other members of the group.
2 members are "getting along" if `(abs(m1->f1 - m2->f1) + abs(m1->f2 - m2-f2)) <= given_hatred`. This is what I tried so far, but doesn't seem to work:

```
//-----helpers-----

//checks if the new candiate member likes the others
static bool fits(Member* a,int curr,int chosen[],double get_along)
{
    for(int i=0; i<curr;i++)
    {
        if(chosen[i]==1)
        {
            int iA=memberGetGAFactorA(a[i]);
            int iB=memberGetGAFactorB(a[i]);
            int currA=memberGetGAFactorA(a[curr]);
            int currB=memberGetGAFactorB(a[curr]);

            if(abs_f(iA-currA)+abs_f(iB-currB)>get_along)
                return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//backtracking
static bool subsum(Members* a, int n, int size, int sum, int chosen[], int curr, double get_allong)
{
    if(sum > size)
        return true;

    if(n <= 0)
        return false;

    if(fits(arr,curr,chosen,get_along))
    {
        chosen[curr]=1;
        int inSum = sum+memberGetFieldNum(a[0]);
        if (subsum(a+1, n-1, size - memberGetFieldNum(a[0]), inSum, chosen, curr + 1, get_along))
            return true;
    }

    chosen [curr] = 0;      
    return subsum(a+1,n-1,size,sum,chosen,curr+1,get_along);
}

//------the wanted function-------
bool subGroupExists(Members* array,length, double get_along)
{
    int* chosen = calloc(length,sizeof(int));
    bool res = subsum(array,length,length/2,0,chosen,0,get_along);

    free(chosen);
    return res;
}
```

I would also mention that Member is an abstract data type that implements all the functions starting with `member....` and it works fine (it is tested).

**Edit:** **I found a workaround I'll post soon, but I'm desperately interested in other solutions, so feel free :)**

Comment: Care to elaborate on `but doesn't seem to work`?

Comment: Sure, well... there are two options every time... true - or false... 
instead of returning the expected answer it always returns true;
I hope that's enough, but if not I can go on, just stay with me here please, I'm very desperate for help !

Comment: You don't have a type for `length` in the subGroupExists() function. In addition, have you tried using gdb or adding print statements to see what the intermediate values are?

Comment: Also  I think you want to check if `size > 0` instead of `sum > size`. You start with `length/2` as size right? and you keep subtracting `getFieldNum`, but you also add `getFieldNum` to the other thing. For example, lets say your list has 6 elements, and the `fieldNum` for element `0` is `2`. Then, your function call will be `subsum(arr, 6, 3, 0, [], 0,..)`, and the first recursion will be `subsum(arr, 5, (3-2), (0 + 2), ...)`, and it will return true because `2 > 1`, even though you could pack more elements in. Instead of `sum > size`, try `size > 0` i.e. (while I can still add stuff.